# Add Facebook to UIActivityViewController shares

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to let my `iOS` app to share using the `UIActivityViewController`, my problem is i can only share with *Message* and *Mail* . In other words the apps that are appear in the `UIActivityViewController` are only the Message and Mail .
How could I add the *FaceBook* or *Twitter* to them .

**Here is my code**

```
        UIButton *shareButton=(UIButton*)sender;
        UIActivityViewController *activityVC=[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:
       @[@"Programmatically Shared post Just for testing ",
       [ [videosList objectAtIndex:shareButton.tag ]videoUrl]] 
        applicationActivities:nil];
```

> I am already logged in with FaceBook App and it is shown when i trying
>   to share using another app.

Comment: you should be login in facebook or twitter through setting app .OR You should have Facebook and Twitter app installed

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not logged in to Facebook or Twitter in the devices Settings. They won't show up here unless the user is logged in.

Looks like you are not attaching the URL perfectly :

```
NSString *shareText = @"Text";

NSURL *shareURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite.com"];

NSArray *items   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    shareText,
                    _shareImage,
                    shareURL, nil];


UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
[activityViewController setValue:shareText forKey:@"subject"];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I am already logged in with FaceBook App and it is shown when i trying to share using another app.

Comment: You have to do Login from device settings. In actual device.@AhdRadwan

Comment: I am using a real device and i can share using Photos app on Facebook

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* dataToShare = @[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file url"]; 

// ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController= [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```